# Any idea why this jquery on click isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to click a class with jquery in wordpress.   Here is my code

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class Scroller {
    constructor() {
        this.events();
    }
    events() {
        alert("hi");
        $(".load-more").on("click", this.test_func.bind(this));
    }

    test_func() {
        alert("yo");
    }
}
```

When i run this code the alert for hi shows up, but then when i click .load-more nothing happens.

I know jquery is set up because when i run this js file (targetting the same class) instead, it works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(document).on('click', '.load-more:not(.loading)', function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the input is not rendered the moment you try to add the handler. Try using this syntax to add you `test_func` click handler:

```
$(document).on('click','.load-more', this.test_func.bind(this));
```

If your element is dynamically added then the above is the only way the handler will be added properly to the click event due to Event Delegation. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33279198/10353987).

Answer (score 1):

That's because you told jQuery to attach the desired event to all of the **current existing** data. in other words - if you created the `.load-more` element after you declared of the event, jQuery will not attach the desired event to the desired selector.

You can go with 2 options:

- 1. Create the element, and then add the event like you specified in your first example.
- 2. Use `$(document).on('click', '.load-more:not(.loading)', callback)`.

Comment: Thank you, this works!  I'm a little confused though.  I don't create the element after the page is loaded.  It's part of the html of the page.  I also have an almost identical page for a different site where the $(".load-more") way works

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea There can be some other reasons that may cause you this behavior. Although, I can't know exactly why it happens since you haven't presented the full code.